# Symfony2 : cannot load resource "."

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I'm having an issue with assets management in Symfony2. I keep getting the following error :

```
Cannot load resource ".".
```

I've been trying to fix it in my config and routing files for dev environment, but the only thing I really did was changing the `use_controller` to `false` in the `config_dev.yml` file.

I keep summoning my resources in my templates with

```
{% stylesheets '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/style.css'
                            filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

and I keep getting the exception :

```
Cannot load resource ".".
```

Any tips on what could go wrong? (I've cleared the cache several times)

Thanks in advance

Edit :

I've tried removing :

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic
```

from my routing_dev.yml file, and the error disappears (with, of course, the resources in my page)

Reedit :

After a complete reinstallation, it seems to be working again. Probably some property I had changed unvoluntarily... Case closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run the following commands:

```
php app/console assets:install web
php app/console assetic:dump
```

Comment: I tried but I'm getting the same error. I'm currently installing a new Symf to see if that changes anything...

Comment: not helpful, the problem stems from bad entry in routing.yml file

Answer (score 10):

In my case it was related to `LiipImagineBundle`, I had these lines at my `Proyect/FrontendBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` file:

```
_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine
```

Comment: Could you mention what to do with these lines? I have the same error and was able to fix it by deleting these lines. But I can't speak for the masses.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had an entry in `routing.yml` for an package I removed from `AppKernel.php`.  After I removed the routing entry, the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I remember having a similar issue some times ago, try to add this line in /app/config/config_dev.yml:

```
assetic: 
    use_controller: true
```

Then clean your cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Then:

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. As I said in my edited post, I reinstalled Symfony and it's working now.

Comment: if you want to use `use_controller false` then dont follow this suggestion, check your routing files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my routing.yml was the following:

```
api:
    resource: "."
    type:     "api"
    prefix: "/api"
```

After removing these lines, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Check your assetic configuration, 
if your going to use

```
assetic:  
    use_controller: false
```

Then check your routing file, comment out the lines

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic
```

That routing entry is not needed when not using assetic's auto compiling.